# clear text in extjs textfield

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs textfield in one of the grids in a webpage. This is how i have created the textfield

```
{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'logicrelation',
            allowBlank: true
}
```

I want to clear this textfield in one of the handlers. I tried clearing it like this, `Ext.get('logicrelation').setValue("");` but I get a message in the console that the setValue function is not available. I tried reset function also and that did not help either. Appreciate your help

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Ext.get`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.html#method-Ext-get) returns `Ext.Element`s.

You are looking for [`Ext.getCmp`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Ext-more.html#method-Ext-getCmp).

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I didnt realise that ext.get will not give the component. Thanks for quickly answering it